# Trying to run some cloud code on Parse.com and I get "Update failed with internal error"

Tags: javascript, parse-platform

I'm trying to set a default value to a variable using cloud code. The code I'm running is:

```
Parse.Cloud.beforeSave("Parse.User", function(request, response) {
if (!request.object.get("score")) {
    request.object.set("score", 60.0);
}
response.success();
});
```

When I run `parse deploy` , I'm getting `Update failed with internal error`. Is there something I'm doing wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Remove quotes from "Parse.User":

```
Parse.Cloud.beforeSave(Parse.User, function(request, response) {
    if (!request.object.get("score")) {
        request.object.set("score", 60.0);
    }
    response.success();
});
```